# Hosting in Firebase without the hyphen and project id

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

It is probably an easy question but I am not able to figure it out. I have a project that I have configured in Firestore to have a domain like "loremipsum.web.app". However, when I do the firebase init and then firebase deploy, it is hosted in "loremipsum-9dd7.web.app" which is the project id. I would like to have it without the hyphen and that id number. How can I do it?

Here’s a screenshot of the hosting section of my project. The first one is the one I want to host in and the second one is where it is hosting.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: "a project that I have configured in Firestore to have a domain like "loremipsum.web.app" => Can you detail what you exactly mean by this sentence? maybe show a screenshot of the console

Comment: I already updated my question and included a screenshot of the hosting section in my project.

Comment: Have a look at Tarik's answer!

Comment: For future screenshots of the Firebase console, I recommend adding `?hl=en` to the URL, so that the labels show up in English and are readable for more people here.

Comment: Ok! Sorry about that. I didn't know I could do that. Thank you! I am going to try to get the hosting in the main domain according to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

That is something you can't do. The reason there are those numbers is that someone else already is using that app name `loremipsum` for his project. When you have choosen your Firebase project name you had the same and Firebase added those numbers to make your project name unique.

Just to make it clear. Even if your name is as you tiped it the "real" project name will be the one with the numbers as you can see on this example:
[image]
I can see in most places the name I tiped in but Firebase will use the one with the numbers for hosting.

[image]

So if you would use the domain without the numbers you would land on his project and not yours.

To have a nice domain just connect a custom one to your Firebase project. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain).

It looks like you manually added a second site to your project. You should check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites) documentation on how to handle such situations. You need to change your firebase configuration and defined on witch target to deploy your site.

Comment: Thank you about your answer but I believe it is not accurate. When I try to visit that main domain, it says that there is no site and that nothing has been deployed yet. I also have that domain available in my project configuration in the Firestore console. So I guess I could deploy there with some configuration but I don't know where to change it.

Comment: I updated my answer. There is absolutely no way for you to have both of hem with the `web.app` domain in a single project. You can see on some places your original name you tiped in but Firebase will use the one with the numebrs. Can you share with us a screenshot of your hosting domains?

Comment: I have updated my question and included a screenshot of the hosting section in my project. I hope it is fine for clarification. Thanks!

Comment: OK. You manually added a second side to your project. I have updated the answer on the last part. Now you need to change your firebase configuration and define the targets for each site. You can find more info about it here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites